# find_package()-ing in Visual Studio does not discover include directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, point-cloud-library

In my project I am using:

```
find_package(PCL REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io search features registration)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

CMAKE-ing the project finds installed `PCL` and `${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}` contains `"C:/Program Files/PCL 1.9.1/include/pcl-1.9"`.

But when I then try to compile, the included header files are not found.

`9>c:\...\runregistration.cpp(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pcl/point_types.h': No such file or directory`

This only happens in **Visual Studio**. When I cmake&compile through command line, the `pcl` headers are found.

What am I doing wrong, what can be different in VS? Is there some configuration I don't know about?

Thanks.

---

**Edit:**

The command line commands I am using are

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ..
cmake --build . --target Target --config Release -- /m:8 /p:CL_MPCount=16
```

I have the **Visual Studio** project open as a directory, navigating to the Project's Properties does not display anything. I have cleared the cache and rebuilt the project, the cmake command **VS** uses is

```
cmake.exe"  -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\...\install\x64-Release" -Wno-dev -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES="Release" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:/Users/matus/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" "PROJECT_DIR"
```

I haven't downloaded `pcl` by `vcpkg` so I am assuming that nothing collides there.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you verify that the `PCL_INCLUDE_DIR` is added to the Project's Properties? You can view this by right-clicking on the Project in the Solution Explorer, navigating to Properties, then select **C/C++** in the left pane, and look in the **Additional Include Directories** field for the PCL include directory.

Comment: Also, it may be helpful to know what `cmake` commands you use in the command line to generate the Visual Studio solution, and which ones you use to build from the command line. Are you sure you cleaned the CMake cache and re-built *from scratch* before attempting the Visual Studio build?

Comment: Thank you for the welcoming and the quick reply. I have added some description to the question.